# Android app that processes QR code (scan+custom action)

Tags: android, qr-code

I use QR codes at my work, generated by suppliers. 
Actually I need to record all those items manually via a website.

The QR code includes all that data, so I want to create an app that automatices the action.

For example, a QR code says "AAA|BBB|CCC|123". I want an app that reads it, and redirects the user browser to an URL: http://myserver.com/qr?data=AAA|BBB|CCC|123". I'll do the processing server-side and output the result page as a html page.

What methods are available for doing that?

Answer (score 2):

[zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) has everything you are looking for. You can start the application with a simple intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, MAIN_ZXING);
```

Or you can use their custom intent that will prompt the user to install their application if it's missing on the device.

Whatever the QR code scans as is returned to your application, then you just have to set up the redirection.

Comment: Better yet, use the supplied `IntentIntegrator`, which takes care of a few more elements you need to take care of here. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent